# Angular search after click event

Tags: angular, button, search, visual-studio-code, angular-material

I'm working with Angular recently and I need a help.

I have a table with Angular Material and in this table I have a lot of items and I have a "search box" like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="SearchText" placeholder="Filtra i risultati" style="color: black;">                     
</mat-form-field>

<button mat-button (click)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" class="search-button">
  <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
</button>
```

TS

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim();
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
}
```

Practically the result I want to achieve is that the list of items must appear only after writing something in the box and clicking on the button.

So the table is initially empty.

I write something and I click on the search-button and the requested results appear.

How can i get this result?
Can you help me with HTML and TS?

Thanks

Comment: Check the console for errors

Answer (score 2):

Change `(click)="applyFilter($event.target.value)"` with `(click)="applyFilter(SearchText)"`

`$event.target.value` means value of the same input element, here you need input value from button element. So use model value `SearchText`

Try like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput [(ngModel)]="SearchText" placeholder="Filtra i risultati" style="color: black;">                     
</mat-form-field>

<button mat-button (click)="applyFilter(SearchText)" class="search-button">
  <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
</button
```

Comment: Do I need to change my TS?
Because when I click on the button-search it still doesn't work.

Comment: `console.log(filterValue )` in your .ts. If it is the same as whatever you typed, you are good to go. No need to change anything, provided your backend is working fine. DO REMEMBER, YOU HAVE MAKE THE API CALL AGAIN. Only setting datasource filter value won't work

Comment: Yes, with console.log(filterValue) I have the same result that I search but nothing happens in the table. Does not filter. :(

Comment: Check your backend.

Comment: I have this error in console:
Unexpected token look for something in JSON at position 0.
Where "look for something" is the word I searched for.